# How to do keypress like Java Robot in Flutter Desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I am stuck with my flutter desktop application development. I'm looking for features like Java Robot for send keypress from my Flutter desktop application. Unfortunately, I did not find any Flutter desktop plugin or core functionality in Flutter.

```
Robot r = new Robot();    
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
```

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-html/KeyEvent-class.html

Comment: It's key event listener. It’s not what i'm looking for. You might not familiar with java Robot keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not have any APIs for posting synthetic events to the OS. You would need to write native code (either as a plugin, or directly in the native part of your application) for each platform to do that.